# Python and Beautifulsoup issue deleting an empty tag in the soup object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Long time user of SO, just recently created an account.   This is my second attempt at asking a question here.   I am fairly new to Python but have programming experience and very new to web scraping.

**Problem**

I have written a function to download a series of HTML files that are all very similarly formatted.  I am then using BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML files and ultimately load the data into a SQL table.  I am doing a gap analysis on the columns/tables that we have already to see how much is different.   I am trying to read a certain HTML tag and in some cases, there is an extra empty set of tags.  What I really wanted to do was to simply delete this extra entry and move on.  I've tried to use the decompose() function and also trying to reference the value by index and performing a delete.

> `<dt class="dlterm"></dt>`

This is throwing off my columns as I am trying to them later store the column name, datatype and description as a record.  I can't figure out how to delete it and keeping parsing the file.

I can get Python to find the  `<dt class="dlterm"></dt>` and have tried decompose(), the pop() method, I was even considering coming up with an offset and set a variable to 1 when it finds it and then somehow offsetting the rest of the code by 1 for that iteration of the loop.

One solution which I have already gotten to work is to go around this completely by opening the source file and replacing the  `<dt class="dlterm"></dt>` tag before I attempt to read this in using beautifulsoup.   To borrow a term from an old co-worker, that is the "weasely way" out.  It would work but seems like a lot of code for a simple problem.

**Question**

I thought that the soup object was a list but it is not behaving that way?  What is the proper term for the soup object?

**Python code snippet**

```
# Load the cursor/recordset
myrecordset = mycursor.fetchall() 

# Outer loop
    for y in myrecordset:

        myfilepath = "myexample.html" % y[2]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(myfilepath),"html.parser")

        PageName = soup.find("h1",{"class":"topictitle1"})

        # print ("PageName: " + PageName.text)
            FieldName = soup.find_all("dt", {"class":"dlterm"})
            FieldDataType = soup.find_all("samp", {"class":"codeph"})
            FieldDesc = soup.find_all("dd", {"class":"ddexpand"})
            # outercounter = -1
            #
            # #Fix the empty value issue early that is offsetting everything
            # for z in FieldName:
            #     outercounter+=1
            #     # FieldName[7].decompose()
            #     if z.text == '': # '<dt class="dlterm"></dt>':
            #         z.decompose()
            #
            #         # FieldName[outercounter-1].pop()
    
    
    
            # How to get get the description cleaned up
            # FieldDesc[2].text.replace('\n','').replace('      ', ' ')
            # print(FieldName.text)
            # print(FieldDataType.text)
            # print(FieldDesc.text)
    
            # inner loop
            innercounter1 = 0
            # zip allows me to iterate through multiple lists at the same time
            for (fn, fdt, fd) in zip(FieldName, FieldDataType, FieldDesc):
    
                fntemp= ''
                fdttemp= ''
                fdtemp= ''
    
                fntemp = fn.text
                fdttemp = fdt.text
    
                # clean the string
                if fd.text.__contains__('One of:'):
                    # hold onto the double return while I replace the others.
                    fdtemp = fd.text.replace('\n\n', '<<nn>>')
                    fdtemp = fdtemp.replace('\n',', ')
                    fdtemp = fdtemp.replace('<<nn>>', '\n')
                else:
                    fdtemp = fd.text.replace('\n', ' ')
    
                fdtemp = fdtemp.strip()
    
                # remove all redundant spaces from the string
                fdtemp = " ".join(fdtemp.split())
                # have to escape single quotes in text so it will insert correctly
                fdtemp = fdtemp.replace("'", "''")

                #Insert into SQL

                # ... code continued
```

**Snippet from HTML file showing the issue**

```
<div class="section">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Title</h2>
<dl>
<dt class="dlterm">Term1</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah blah about term1</dd>
<dt class="dlterm">Term2</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah blah about term2</dd>
<dt class="dlterm"></dt><dt class="dlterm">Term3</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah about term3</dd>
</dl></div>
```

If someone could help me figure this out it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) is enough to solve your problem.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="section">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Title</h2>
<dl>
<dt class="dlterm">Term1</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah blah about term1</dd>
<dt class="dlterm">Term2</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah blah about term2</dd>
<dt class="dlterm"></dt><dt class="dlterm">Term3</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah about term3</dd>
</dl></div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('dt',attrs={"class":"dlterm"}): #all dl tags with class dlterm
    if not tag.text: #if tag is empty
        tag.decompose()
print(soup)
```

Output

```
<div class="section">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Title</h2>
<dl>
<dt class="dlterm">Term1</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah blah about term1</dd>
<dt class="dlterm">Term2</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah blah about term2</dd>
<dt class="dlterm">Term3</dt><dd><samp class="codeph">nonNegativeInteger</samp></dd><dd class="ddexpand">Blah blah about term3</dd>
</dl></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here.  I am using PyCharm and it seems like the debugger is not showing me the correct variable values when stepping through.   The odd thing is that if I simply look at the soup variable before and after like you did above in my code the bad tag is now gone.   So now I'm no longer shifted on my columns further down.   I am later using zip to step through three similar variables at the same time.   This was offsetting the values and screwing it up from that point downward.  Now I have a new issue to solve for but I'm not stuck.